# Mat-tab: ativar outra tab ao clicar em botão

Tags: html, angular, typescript, front-end, angular-material

Estou iniciando em Angular e tenho ainda dúvidas em relação a interação entre componentes. No meu caso em específico não sei como fazer, e se tem como.

```
        <mat-tab-group>
            <mat-tab label="Pesquisa">
                <app-recursos-pesquisa></app-recursos-pesquisa>
            </mat-tab>

            <mat-tab label="Cadastro">
                <app-recursos-cadastro></app-recursos-cadastro>
            </mat-tab>
        </mat-tab-group>
```

Dentro do componente *app-recursos-pesquisa* tenho um botão 'Novo cadastro'. O que quero fazer é, quando clicar nele, a mat-tab Cadastro seja acionada, direcionando assim para essa tab.

[image: Este é o botão que será acionado]

[image: Esta é a tab que desejo que seja aberta ao clicar no botão]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os componentes Material tem diversas interações, métodos e propriedades.
no caso do [`MatTab`](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview) não é diferente. O seletor [`mat-tab-group`](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api#MatTabGroup) tem diversas propriedades dentre elas o `selectedIndex` que é responsável por indicar o index da aba que esta ativa no momento.

Abaixo segue um exemplo de como usar:

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  selected = new FormControl(0);
  reset = 0;
  constructor(){}
  
  ngOnInit(){
    this.selected.valueChanges.subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.reset = data;
      }
    })
  }

}
```

> app.component.html

```
<div style="height: 500px;">
  <mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selected.value" 
    (selectedIndexChange)="selected.setValue($event)">
    <mat-tab label="Pesquisar">
      <app-pesquisar-recursos (changeIndex)="selected.setValue($event)" ></app-pesquisar-recursos>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Cadastrar">
      <app-cadastrar-recurso [reset]="reset"></app-cadastrar-recurso>
    </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
</div>
```

O "changeIndex" pode ser encontrado no componente de pesquisa usando o `decorator` `@Output()`. o mesmo é usado para enviar informações de um componente filho para um componente pai.

> pesquisar-recursos.component.ts

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pesquisar-recursos',
  templateUrl: './pesquisar-recursos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pesquisar-recursos.component.scss']
})
export class PesquisarRecursosComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() changeIndex = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public adicionarRecurso() {
    this.changeIndex.emit(1);
  }
}
```

> pesquisar-recursos.component.html

```
<div>
  <h3>Pesquisar</h3>
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="adicionarRecurso()"
    class="example-delete-tab-button">
    adicionar Recurso
  </button>
  
</div>
```

Caso precise alterar algo no componente cadastro quando abrir a aba de cadastro o `@Input() reset` recebe a mudança de valor e com a função `ngOnChanges()` você pode ver as mudanças deste `@Input`.

> cadastrar-recurso.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cadastrar-recurso',
  templateUrl: './cadastrar-recurso.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cadastrar-recurso.component.scss']
})
export class CadastrarRecursoComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() reset = 0;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngOnChanges(){

    console.log('teste ' + this.reset);
    if(this.reset == 1){
      console.log('teste ' + this.reset);
    }
  }

}
```

Para mais informações consulte a documentação do [angular material](https://material.angular.io/components/categories) e documentação oficial do angular sobre [`@Input() and @Output() properties`](https://docs.angular.lat/guide/inputs-outputs).

Comment: Obrigada! A minha dúvida é se eu posso adicionar um evento de click no componente 1 e executar a ação no componente 2, isso é possível?

Comment: Certo. é possível sim. vou modificar minha resposta.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, estou dando uma lida na documentação que sugeriu. Apenas uma última dúvida ficou, se eu quisesse, por exemplo, ativar a tab como você fez, e resetar o form que tenho dentro do componente  <app-cadastrar-recurso> seria muito difícil de fazer? Sabe alguma documentação que possa sugerir para eu tentar?

Comment: Na documentação sobre o `@output` também contem conteúdo sobre `@Input`. Basicamente ele é usado para fazer o inverso do `@output` transitando conteúdo do componente pai para um componente filho.  Usando uma função `ngOnChanges` no componente `<app-recursos-cadastro>` poderá obter as mudanças que o `@Input` teve.

Comment: Entendi, vou ler sobre isso. Muito obrigada pela ajuda

Comment: Olá Eustáquio, será que seria possível me ajudar novamente nessa parte?

Comment: Fiz algumas edições com um exemplo de como usar o `@Input()`.